# How to flush left centered part in multline environment?

Tags: math-mode, align, multline

I would like to use `multline` environment, but in that way that centered part be left aligned. With multline centered part is centered, and I would like if we can somehow to aligned it to the left (but to stay centered). And of course, if this is possible to do with `align` environment (but that first line is flush to left and last to the right), **that is better for me**, because than I can label arbitrary equations (because with multline I can label just last one equation). I hope I didn't confuse you too much.

Here you MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{multline}
 A = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\Delta x\left( a^{2}+\left( a^{2}+2a\Delta x
 +\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\right.\\
 +\left( a^{2}+2\cdot 2a\Delta x+2^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\\
 +\left( a^{2}+2\cdot 3a\Delta x+3^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\\
 + \ldots\\
 \left.+\left( a^{2}+2\cdot (n-1)a\Delta x +(n-1)^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right) \right)\\
 = \frac{1}{3}\left( b^{3}-a^{3}\right) + \text{something}
\end{multline}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean like this? (I used an subsidiary `aligned` for the inner alignment)

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{multline}
 A = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\Delta x\left( a^{2}+\left( a^{2}+2a\Delta x
 +\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\right.\\
\begin{aligned} 
 &+\left( a^{2}+2\cdot 2a\Delta x+2^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\\
 &+\left( a^{2}+2\cdot 3a\Delta x+3^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right)\\
 &+ \cdots\\
 &+\left.\left( a^{2}+2\cdot (n-1)a\Delta x +(n-1)^{2}\left( \Delta x\right) ^{2}\right) \right)\\
\end{aligned} \\
 = \frac{1}{3}\left( b^{3}-a^{3}\right) + \text{something}
\end{multline}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\left`, `\right`, use the `\big`, `\bigg`, family of commands as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{multline}
 A = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\Delta x \Bigl( a^{2}+\bigl( a^{2}+2a\Delta x
 + ( \Delta x ) ^{2}\bigr) \\
\begin{aligned} 
 &+ \bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot 2a\Delta x+2^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr)\\
 &+ \bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot 3a\Delta x+3^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr)\\
 &+ \cdots\\
 &+\bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot (n-1)a\Delta x +(n-1)^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr) \Bigr)\\
\end{aligned} \\
 = \frac{1}{3} ( b^{3}-a^{3} ) + \text{something}
\end{multline}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even most of the parentheses can be safely removed.

Comment: Yes, I wanted exactly that! "I used an subsidiary aligned for the inner alignmen" I didn't see that as solution. Thanks. Just one question: what If I want to label for example first, third and last equations. How to do that?

Comment: "Instead of \left, \right, use the \big, \bigg, family of commands." Yes of course. I just copy/paste (and add \text{something}) example from here http://ctan.mirror.ac.za/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf.

Comment: @Cortizol I think that this new requirement qualifies for a new question since it has nothing to do with the alignment issue discussed here. In any case, for the required numbering  I'm afraid you will have to abandon `multline`.

Comment: Okay. I can ask new question (with link to this one), but for some reason, it can look like I am spamming if I ask two questions in 5 minutes. To wait one hour or maybe not?