# How to label equations from this question?

Tags: math-mode, align, labels

**First, please change name of this question (I didn't know how to name this question in appropriate way).**

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256045/how-to-flush-left-centered-part-in-multline-environment) my recently asked question I asked how to align some centered  equations. Now, I would like to have same result, but with labeled first, third and last equation. I suppose now we can not use `multline` environment, because with that environment we can label only last equation. @Gonzalo Medina suggested to ask this as new question. Here you MWE (from his answer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{multline}
 A = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\Delta x \Bigl( a^{2}+\bigl( a^{2}+2a\Delta x
 + ( \Delta x ) ^{2}\bigr) \\
\begin{aligned} 
 &+ \bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot 2a\Delta x+2^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr)\\
 &+ \bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot 3a\Delta x+3^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr)\\
 &+ \cdots\\
 &+\bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot (n-1)a\Delta x +(n-1)^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr)     \Bigr)\\
\end{aligned} \\
 = \frac{1}{3} ( b^{3}-a^{3} ) + \text{something}
\end{multline}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you have only one equation. You like to number their parts?

Comment: @Zarko Yes, parts of the whole equation.

Comment: wouldn't it really be better if the equals sign on the last line were aligned with the equals sign on the first line?  (please see comments to the answer in this regard.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I suppose that answer is yes, but this is just an example. I have some other equations (which I didn't want to show here, it's from my master thesis), and I just wanted to imitate `multline` environment (that is left, centered, ..., centered, right, with labels).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a slightly different solution, with the `alignat` environment, and the `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools`, an extension of `amsmath`. I also suggest another layout, using `alignat` and `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\def\cdotsfill{\leavevmode \leaders\hbox{$\cdots$}\hfill \kern0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{alignat}{2}
  A = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\Delta x \Bigl( a^{2} & +\bigl( a^{2}+2a\Delta x
  + ( \Delta x ) ^{2}\bigr) & & \\
    & + \mathrlap{\bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot 2a\Delta x+2^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr)} & & \notag \\
    & +\mathrlap{ \bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot 3a\Delta x+3^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr)} & & \\
    & + \cdots & & \notag \\
    & +\mathrlap{\bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot (n-1)a\Delta x +(n-1)^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr) \Bigr)} & & \notag \\
    & & & = \frac{1}{3} ( b^{3}-a^{3} ) + \text{something}
\end{alignat}
%
\begin{alignat}{2}
  A & = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\Delta x \Bigl( a^{2} +\bigl( a^{2}&& +2a\Delta x
  + ( \Delta x ) ^{2}\bigr) \\[-1ex]
    & & & \!\begin{aligned} & +\bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot 2a\Delta x+2^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr) \\
  & + \eqmakebox[A]{$ \bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot 3a\Delta x+3^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr) $} \\
  & + \eqmakebox[A]{$\cdotsfill$}\\[-1ex]
  & + \bigl( a^{2}+2\cdot (n-1)a\Delta x +(n-1)^{2} ( \Delta x ) ^{2} \bigr) \Bigr)
  \end{aligned} \\
  & =\mathrlap{\smash[t]{\frac{1}{3}} ( b^{3}-a^{3} ) + \text{something}} &
\end{alignat}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernand! I didn't know for `alignat ` environment. Just one question: I suppose it is safe to use `mathtools` because that is extension  of `amsmath` as you said? I mean, I suppose I can't use both in the same time? That is, I need to switch `amsmath` with `mathtools` and that is it? I am worried because maybe something gone wrong if I use `mathtools` instead `amsmath`. I am probably silly guy, but...

Comment: Oh, I see now question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43860/mathtools-vs-amsmath, so I will just use mathtools. Thanks!

Comment: As you've probably seen, it loads amsmath, so you don't need to load it. In addition, it fixes two amsmath bugs. You should take a look at its documentation, you will see it's really helpful.

Comment: Yes, of course, I will look at its documentation to see what new benefits this package gives (I am really happy). Thank you again, you really helped me. (I didn't forget to accept your answer, but I will leaved it unanswered for some more time because maybe someone other find different solution)

Comment: wouldn't it really be better if the equals sign on the last line were aligned with the equals sign on the first line?  also, lines 2--(n-1) could be handled by `split`, which would then produce only one tag, so `\notag` wouldn't be needed.  (i'm not in a position to test and i won't post an answer unless i can do that so if you want to extend your answer, feel free.)

Comment: @barbara beeton I agree with you for the placement of the equals sign, but I respected the O.P.'s wish to have a layout that looks like multline. I'll add it as a suggestion.

Comment: @Bernard -- i started to post that comment directly to the question, for that reason.  i will do that now, with a pointer to the comments here.

Comment: Maybe you want to edit your answer to add \documentclass{article} \usepackage{mathtools, ..... in code part. As you wish. And thanks again.